# PHP Conditional Check for multiple WordPress Roles

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, conditional-statements, roles

I am looking for more performant code for selecting multiple WordPress roles as a check to run some code:

```
 if ( current_user_can( 'wholesale_customer' ) || current_user_can( 'wholesale_premium' ) || current_user_can( 'wholesale_nz') || current_user_can( 'wholesale_wa') ){
            // do something
     }
```

The above code works but I question is it optimal, from what I understand you can't pass multiple roles into *current_user_can* as an array but more so capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check with `user_roles_array` like this -

```
$user_roles = array( 'wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_premium', 'wholesale_nz', 'wholesale_wa' );
foreach( $user_roles as $role ){
    if( current_user_can( $role ) ){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That `// do something` should probably be followed by a `break;` here though - otherwise, if the user had multiple roles assigned, the `// do something` part would also execute _multiple_ times - which is probably rather not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one -

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$compare_user_roles = array( 'wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_premium', 'wholesale_nz', 'wholesale_wa' );
foreach( $user_roles as $user_role ){
    if( in_array( $user_role, $compare_user_roles ) ){
        // echo $user_role;
    }
}
```

Comment: using `global $current_user` is not preferred.  Use `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`  The way to do this is here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/#comment-4083

Comment: Please flag to close duplicate questions instead of answering.